# Test app pushes to heroku, but doesn't run in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm going through a tutorial on making a ruby app.

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/insta..._rails_app

When I try to visit my app on heroku I get this.

"The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

This is my app info from console.

=== fierce-eyrie-9374
Addons: heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
Dynos: 1
Git URL: #Can only post two links
Owner Email: email@email.com
Region: us
Repo Size: 36k
Slug Size: 29M
Stack: cedar-14
Web URL: https://fierce-eyrie-7862.herokuapp.com/
Workers: 0

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your app works locally, so when you run `rails s` and visit `localhost:3000` you don't get a 404?

I've got the tutorial running on https://intense-castle-6255.herokuapp.com/

Have you run your heroku migrations? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: It worked on neither, I have re-made the app and it works fine now, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Rails app is running, but you might have not defined the root in your routes.rb file. What you are getting is a Rails 404 page from your app.

Comment: I added this to my routes.rb file.

root 'drinks#index'